# Notify client that server has finished processing in firebase

Tags: java, angularjs, firebase

For our application,

- We are using AngularJS as our front-end framework and Java at server-side  in our application.
- We want to integrate our application with Firebase, but we have the following issue regarding it.

Now, let's assume the following scenario:

- The client changes an object stored at any Firebase URL
- The server listens for that change and start processing on that object

  - We can assume this process takes 5 to 10 seconds.
- However, the client changes its state without waiting for a response from the server.

**Our question is:** How will server notify client about completion of processing?

Please guide us how will we implement this functionality. Is there  built in mechanism in Firebase to do this?

Comment: What you're describing is typically implemented using a work queue. See https://github.com/firebase/firebase-work-queue for an example of such a queue.

Answer (score 1):

Just like the server listens to a change in the database, the client can do the same. When the client changes the object in the database, it can create a new property specifically meant for the server to signal when it is finished processing. The client then listens to changes to that property, and the server changes it when it is done processing. Your data structure could look something like this:

```
{
  serverjobs: {
    job1: {
      input: {
        // the client's input for the job
      },
      finished: false
    },
    job2: {
      input: {
        // the client's input for the job
      },
      output: {
        // the server's output for the job
      }
      finished: true
    }
  }
}
```

The server would listen to `serverjobs`, and start working on a job when the client adds it. The client supplies whatever data the server needs for each job as `input`. The client also listens to a job's `finished` value. When the server finishes a job, it sets the `finished` value to `true` and supplies the job's result as `output`. The client notices the change of the `finished` value and can take the `output` and act accordingly.

Comment: hi @Marein this approach will work but is there any built mechanism in firebase to do this as it is a basic requirement in clent server architecture??

Comment: Frank has already answered that question. Since Firebase is a BaaS (i.e. replaces client-to-server architecture), it does not make sense that client-to-server architectural requirements would be built into the API. It is, all the same, terribly simple to accomplish by just treating Firebase as the central authority and transforming all services (client or server) into data consumers with differing privileges (i.e. using a queue).